# Electron enable touch events for a touch screen

Tags: electron, chromium

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to touchscreen and running an electron app on it through the startx command,

```
# startx ./electron-app -- --nocursor
```

the problem that I can't handle the touch events like (touchstart, touchend) and apparently that is because Electron (or chromium) not seeing the screen as a touch screen.

Comment: Is there any difference between Electron menu and WebView related touchscreen behavior?

Comment: Have you checked [this issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/978)? Does it help to solve your problem? Also, which version of Electron are you using?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not that Electron/Blink isn't seeing the touchscreen / native touch events. There are two parts to the problem, as I understand it:

1. You need to ensure you're receiving touch events in the OS from the touchscreen. I haven't tested with Pi/Linux, so I'm not sure if those handle touch events natively. I know that OSX, for one, requires a third-party driver like [UDPP by Touch-Base.
2. Once the OS is handling touch events, those are [piped through to Blink via the Electron wrapper](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/22b21d04bdbb43be52a90a3b05fdbd9b4278feea/atom/common/native_mate_converters/blink_converter.cc#L75-L82). However, you need to set the `touch-events` command-line switch to enable it. My understanding is that that switch is passed through as a [Chromium commandline switch](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/lkcr/content/public/common/content_switches.cc#861).

I found more info on [this thread](https://discuss.atom.io/t/touch-events-and-scrolling/36575/4), though not very much, and still haven't gotten things working on my OSX setup. Electron's documentation is very sparse...the `touch-events` switch isn't even listed in their [CLI docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/chrome-command-line-switches.md). Hope this helps.

Comment: Good documentation on Chrome's commandline switches here as well: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/