# Is it possible to open an electron app by clicking/touching the Windows screen?

Tags: windows, electron

I want to open an Electron JS app when I click or touch the screen.

Another software is gonna be running in the main screen, but at any click/touch, my app is supposed to open.

**Is there some way to listen to the Windows clicks/touches anywhere, and open certain app?**

**Obs.:** *The system is being developed to be executed on a "Midia Totem", and this is the reason I have to do all of this stuff.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electron enable touch events for a touch screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359462/electron-enable-touch-events-for-a-touch-screen)

Answer (score 0):

They answer a similar question here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41836178/4778613

"Once the OS is handling touch events, those are piped through to Blink via the Electron wrapper. However, you need to set the touch-events command-line switch to enable it."